# if last segment equals url title

Tags: conditionals, segments, url-title

I am trying to show an active class if an entry is being viewed but my conditional's are not working:

```
{if last_segment == '{url_title'}  class="active"  {/if}
```

I am using an embed of a list of entries on a product detail page.  I want the active entry to have a class of active

This is not working even though last_segment and url_title are the same

this is my embeded template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" category="{segment_3_category_id}"}

    <li {if last_segment == '{url_title}'} class="active"{/if}><a href="{title_permalink='Products/detail/{segment_3}/{segment_4}'}">{title} &raquo;</a></li>

    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2):

solved: `{if url_title == "{last_segment}"} class="active"{/if}`